# How To Connect Keyboard Using Aux Cable

Tags: keyboard, cable

I have Yamaha PSR E353 model keyboard,
but I don't know kow to connect this keyboard to my home theater system.

I have used an Aux-In cable for this, but it’s not working.

How can I connect this keyboard to my home theater system?

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting a cable from the PHONES/OUTPUT jack on the keyboard to an input on your home theater?

Comment: No I'm used Aux cable. For its, and in keyboard port name is Aux In

Comment: Not uses PHONES/OUTPUT Jack on the keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used Aux cable, and keyboard port name is Aux In

This is the problem! :)

As you will see from page 30 of the manual [here](https://usa.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/1/333251/psre353_en_om_a0.pdf), the Aux *in* port is when you want to play a song out of the Yamaha PSR E353's speakers:

[image]

If you want the sound to come out of the Yamaha, **you need to use the PHONES/OUTPUT jack**. Again from the manual:

[image]

So you need to connect the PHONES/OUTPUT jack to your home theatre system. It looks like the plug is a different size, but if you have something like a 3.5mm Stereo to 6.3mm 1/4-inch Adapter... [image]

...you may be able to use the same wire.

Comment: Basic - if a port says 'in' it's for a signal to go 'in'. Same idea with 'out'.